# Watcher free, bindonce like alternative for ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[Bindonce](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce) and [angular-once](https://github.com/tadeuszwojcik/angular-once) allow for watcher-free binding on the data that is loaded only once. I was wondering why these solutions do not include an equivalent for `ng-repeat`.

One possible use case for this would be to load a list that does not change.

I figured that this should be a quite commonly required feature so it should already be implemented, but to my surprise, I couldn't find it anywhere.

Is this already been done?
Is there a technical limitation that I need to keep in mind if I try to do it myself?
Or is this just a case of micro-optimization and not something I should waste much time on?

Comment: [Lazy one-time binding](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/cee429f0aaebf32ef1c9aedd8447a48f163dd0a4) is available since AngularJS 1.3.0-beta.10

Comment: Could anyone please explain the downvote on this question? I'm all for making it better.

Comment: @Blackhole great to know! But since 1.3 is still in beta, upgrading won't be a proper solution to this question.

Comment: There's a release candidate [for two days](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/releases/tag/v1.3.0-rc.0) :) .

Answer (score 0):

`bindonce` actually does support ng-repeat pretty well if you put the core directive on the outer ng-repeat element wrapper. Its one caveat is that it still makes one watcher for the outer element itself - it can't eliminate that last one.

As noted above, Angular 1.3.x (and not even the latest - it's in ...14, which came out a few months ago) has the '::' operator for expressions. Also as noted above this doesn't apply to Angular 1.2.x... but if that's actually what you want then there is no answer. New development (both core and plugins) has focused on 1.3.x and up (2.x is being planned now) so you're not going to find something new that solves this there.

As for whether it's a micro-optimization... it depends. How many elements do you have in your repeat, how often are you triggering digests, and how powerful are your users' browsers? There's no hard and fast rule on what to shoot for here. The rule of thumb is supposed to be 2000 or more, but I have an app with well over 6000 and it's working fine - albeit on a screen that doesn't change much anyway so there aren't a lot of digests going on. The same thing in a repeat with a filter and a few triggers a second is going to *crawl*. You need to measure the performance to know for sure.